# failed to parse date field Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in elasticsearch 6.2.4, for which i created a new index in new elasticsearch cluster 7.6.1.

I have copied the mapping for this index from 6.2.4 to 7.6.1, but when i tried to _reindex from 6.2.4 to 7.6.1.

I get the below error.

```
  "failures" : [
{
  "index" : "newindex",
  "type" : "_doc",
  "id" : "someid",
  "cause" : {
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse field [UPDATES.when] of type [date] in document with id 'someid'. Preview of field's value: '1.528501444E9'",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "failed to parse date field [1.528501444E9] with format [epoch_second]",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "date_time_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"
      }
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

_reindex call done at 7.6.1's kibana

```
POST _reindex/?pretty
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://oldserver:9200"

    },
    "index": "oldindex",
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "newindex"
  }
}
```

Mapping of updates field is same in both places

```
"UPDATES" : {
          "properties" : {
            "key" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "when" : {
              "type" : "date",
              "format" : "epoch_second"
            }
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: in the original index it is stored as in the format as  "when": 1523274629 (ignore the number, check the format)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the timestamp which is appearing in one of your date feild 1.528501444E9  is UNIX timestamp in scientific notation.

But Elasticsearch fails because it can't parse 1.528501444E9 since I suppose as per you exception the format that you have given for this field is `epoch_second` which does not take this format.

You can read futher related to this format from here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: but i was able to make mapping in the 7.6.1 in epoch_second, only when i am _reindexing it fails.  in the original index it is stored as in the format as "when": 1523274629 (ignore the number, check the format)

Comment: you can see in the link given by you that epoch_second is supported

Comment: yes epoch_second is supported but issue is when you pass this value 1.528501444E9 it throws error but when you pass this kind of value 1523274629 it works fine

Comment: The value being passed is by _reindex & the actual value stored is in this format "when": 1523274629

Comment: Have you created mapping of this newindex similar to old index before running reindex API

Comment: @penta, looks like you finally was able to get the Elasticsearch logs from your docker ?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja haha lol no, i moved on with that issue as i saw that for some documents the same fields were not present